# Not able to load the dropdownlist in the jquery datatable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu, datatables

I have an issue with loading dropdown list in a table with jQuery DataTables. Can someone please help me on this issue?

The below is the code I have written to load the dropdown list.

```
$('#grdCurrentOrder_PriceBook').dataTable({

  "bServerSide": true,
  "sAjaxSource": "../PriceBook/AjaxHandler",
  "bProcessing": true,
  "scrollY": 385,
  "scrollX": true,
  "scrollCollapse": true,
  "jQueryUI": true,
  "bJQueryUI": true,
  "sDom": 'lfrtip',
  "aoColumns": [{
      "sName": "Item"
    }, {
      "sName": "ItemDesc"
    }, {
      "sName": "UM",
      "mRender": function(sName) {

        var data = {
          '0': 'India',
          '1': 'USA',
          '2': 'Australia',
          '3': 'Srilanka'
        };

        var s = $('<select id="dynamic_select" />');

        for (var val in data) {
          $('<option />', {
            value: val,
            text: data[val]
          }).appendTo(s);
        }


        return '<td>' + s.appendTo('td:nth-child(3)') + '</td>';

        return '<select id="dynamic_select" name="dynamic_select">\n\
           <option id="0" value="">Select</option/>\n\
          <option id="1" value="test.php">' + data[0] + '</option/>\n\        <option id="2" value="test2.php">' + data[1] + '</option/>\n\
         <option id="31" value="test3.php">' + data[2] + '</option/>\n\
         </select>';
      },
    }
  ],

  "oLanguage": {
    "sProcessing": 'Processing.....'
  }
});
```

There is somewhere I m doing wrong while appending the `select` tag. It is getting appending multiple time in the same row.

[image]

If I hardcode the return type `select` it works fine.

```
return '<td>' + s.appendTo('td:nth-child(3)') + '</td>';

return 
   '<select id="dynamic_select" name="dynamic_select">\n\
    <option id="0" value="">Select</option/>\n\
    <option id="1" value="test.php">' + data[0] + '</option/>\n\
    <option id="2" value="test2.php">' + data[1] + '</option/>\n\
    <option id="31" value="test3.php">' + data[2] + '</option/>\n\
    </select>';
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're overcomplicating this - You want a hardcoded selectlist in the first column of every row?

```
"aoColumns": [
 {
    'mRender': function(data, type, full) {
        return '<select id="dynamic_select" name="dynamic_select">' +
               '<option id="0" value="India">Select</option/>' +
               '<option id="1" value="USA"></option/>' +
               '<option id="2" value="test2.php"></option/>' +
               '<option id="31" value="test3.php"></option/>' +
               '</select>';
        }
   },
   { "sName": "Item" },
   { "sName": "ItemDesc" }
]
```

I may have missed something as I'm not sure why you would hard-code the selectlist data, but then try to loop over it to create the controls...

Comment: That's not a valid code, you forgot `mRender` function definition.

Comment: I dont want to hard code the return type of mRender. When i loop the selectlist and try to append it to td . This display multiple times.          


    "mRender": function(sName) {

        var data = {
          '0': 'India',
          '1': 'USA',
          '2': 'Australia',
          '3': 'Srilanka'
        };

        var s = $('<select id="dynamic_select" />');

        for (var val in data) {
          $('<option />', {
            value: val,
            text: data[val]
          }).appendTo(s);
        }


        return '<td>' + s.appendTo('td:nth-child(3)') + '</td>';

Comment: The question is confusing. Why are you appending the selectlist to a `<td>`? Why are you looping over `data` when you've already hard-coded it?